# Расчет периода между импульсами входящего сигнала

Tags: c, avr

Получаю сигнал (от 3 кГц до 125 кГц) на ICP1 (ATmega16), и не знаю как правильно рассчитать период между импульсами (между нисходящим и восходящим фронтами). Нужно определить, что между импульсами - период или два периода. Как это можно реализовать на СИ?

Прошу помощи советом в нужном направлении или примером кода.

Comment: Вот здесь: *http://microsin.net/programming/AVR/atmega-ct1-pulse-counting.html*, как мне кажется, достаточно подробно всё расписано.

Answer (score 3):

Например в лоб, можно так:

```
#include <time.h>

double elapsed; // in milliseconds
clock_t start, end;

start = clock();

// ваш код между приходом сигнала

end = clock();

elapsed = ((double) (end - start) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Второй, более точный (все относительно) вариант в лоб:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
unsigned long start,end;
rdtscl(start);
// ваш код по отлову импульсов...
rdtscl(end);

printf("cpu clics: %lu\n",(end-start));
```

если rtdscl не обнаружено :) можно не отчаиваться и перейти к его реализации:

```
 #define rdtscl(dest) \
    __asm__ __volatile__("mfc0 %0,$9; nop" : "=r" (dest))
```

Есть ещё такой подход:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

   timespec ts;
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts); // FreeBSD
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts); // Linux
```

Так же можно посмотреть Реал тайм функции кернеля, и сделать на них, зависит от реализации кернеля, префикс __rt_*

Comment: А как можно рассчитать период без библиотеки time.h?

Comment: На syscall из кернеля, смотреть чего умеет кернель по функциям.

Comment: Вот список примерно что может быть, искать по словам [time, clock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), Надо подключить `include <sys/syscall.h>` и звать примерно так: `syscall(SYS_имя_функции, параметры, ...,параметры);`

Comment: Но `<sys/syscall.h>` для линукса, а я пытаюсь это сделать на винде в codevisionavr

Comment: Там кернель то есть в этом авр? Там же какой-то из линухов собран, в чем проблема. И syscall можно самому на асме написать, там 4 строчки, для вызова из кернель спайс. То есть всякие хеадеры не понадобяться

Comment: Вот [список](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) вам подойдёт например 201 номер функции, это и есть вызов `time(...)`, и пример как его [позвать](https://eax.me/linux-assembler/) без всяких хеадеров и библиотек. Теоретический студия должна моделировать эти обращения, если установлен SDK, на практике не проверял под ARM. Syscall сам по себе и есть `int 0x80` в асме под х32 и `syscall` под х64